# Homebrew: Install latest npm version next to node@8

Tags: node.js, npm, homebrew

**The situation**:

I am using the LTS version of node, i.e. node@8 and installed it with homebrew on macOS High Sierra. It comes packaged with it's own version of `npm`, i.e. `npm v5.6.0`.

When I type `which node` I also get `/usr/local/opt/node@8/bin/node` which is the npm version inside the `node@8` package.

When I run `npm install -g npm`, the console outputs:

```
/usr/local/bin/npx -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npx-cli.js
/usr/local/bin/npm -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
+ npm@6.3.0
added 1 package and updated 3 packages in 9.884s
```

...but `npm --version` still shows me that I'm on `5.6.0`.

**Question**:

Given that, how do I update `npm` to version `6` independently of `node` with homebrew or npm?

Comment: What is the output of `echo $PATH`?

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni The beginning of my output of `echo $PATH` is `/usr/local/opt/node@8/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`. I now made sure `usr/local/opt/node@8` appears after `/usr/local/bin` in my PATH and now I get `6.3.0` when running `npm --version`. Thanks! :-) I'll make a proper reply out of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short version**:

Make sure `usr/local/bin` appears before `/usr/local/opt/node@8/bin` in your `PATH`.

---

**Long version**:

While installing `node@8` I added `export PATH=/usr/local/opt/node@8/bin:$PATH` for some reason to my `.bash_profile` (or perhaps `.bash_rc` in your case) which placed `/usr/local/opt/node@8/bin` at the **beginning** of my path, i.e. the first few entries of my PATH were: `usr/local/opt/node@8/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin ...` in my case.

In this scenario `npm` searched for an executable in `/usr/local/opt/node@8/bin` first (and found `/usr/local/opt/node@8/bin/npm` which points to version 5) before searching in `/usr/local/bin` where it would've found `/usr/local/bin/npm` (which points to version 6).

So I removed `export PATH=/usr/local/opt/node@8/bin:$PATH` from `.bash_profile`. I could've also changed the entry in `.bash_profile` to `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/opt/node@8/bin` which appends `/usr/local/opt/node@8/bin` to the **end** of the PATH instead of adding it to the beginning of the PATH.

Now `npm` first searches for executables in `/usr/local/bin` and finds version 6.

Thanks to @OrtomalaLokni for pointing me to the PATH in your comment.

---

**Additional note**: Adding `/usr/local/opt/node@8/bin` to the PATH is not necessary since `brew link node@8` creates a symlink for *node* which can be observed when running `ls -lh /usr/local/bin/npm`, that is, `/usr/local/bin/node` points to `/usr/local/opt/node@8/bin/node`.

Right now I can't recall anymore why I initially added `/usr/local/opt/node@8/bin` to the PATH.